# Simple way to remove unused dependencies from POM in Spring Initializr web project (IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.1)

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I created one simple Spring Initializr web project in Intellij Idea. After project creation, I see only two dependencies (`spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-test`) in `pom.xml` file but the `External Libraries` in project structure does contain many unused jars (Which obviously degrades the performance). See the below screenshot.

[image]

Is there any shortcut or manual way to remove unused dependencies and keep only the required ones?

**Edit**

Though `Remove Unused Resources` option is available (right click on `External Libraries` then `Refactor` option) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why are you concerned about this? More likely than not these are transitive dependencies that are required by the maven plugin, spring boot web, and the test dependencies.

Additionally removing dependencies you don't think you need will lead to runtime exceptions when a required class isn't found. Spring manages dependencies

Answer (score 3):

you can try `dependency:analyze`, it will help you. the main goal of `dependency:analyze` is analyse the dependencies in to the project and determines that which are `used and declared` and  `used and undeclared` and `unused and declared`.

you can also refer below link for reference for more study:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

you can try to run `mvn dependency:tree`,  this won't remove dependencies
 but it is allow you to do the analysis yourself

Comment: Thanks Mayank!!! While digging up the solution of my prob I came across this ans on StackOverflow itself. This definitely analyze the dependency problems in eclipse Maven project but unfortunately not in IntelliJ. Anyway I will try the last command you mentioned and let's see.

Comment: I ran the command in the project root directory, but unfortunately seems no changes.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` only create dependency conflicts, to find out why Commons Collections. for more refer https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html. after find you can remove dependency manually.